# Grammar question : "I think it is right that women be involved in the policies"

Tags: subjunctives

I'm watching Emma Watson's speech on gender equality. 
She says

> I think it is right that women be involved in the policies

I understand the meaning all right but can anyone explain grammar behind this sentence? I mean "women be involved" . 
The verb "be" is right after the subject "women." For example, I guess "It is right that women to be involved" or "It is right that women should be involved" would be the right alternatives. 
Is it colloquial or grammatically correct expression to say that sentence without 'to' or 'should' etc? If so, why is it? 
Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Comment: Related question, [When should I use the subjunctive mood?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/when-should-i-use-the-subjunctive-mood). There is a great answer in the linked question. When you see the following adjectives in a that clause, you can use the bare infinitive form of a verb, *necessary, desirable, imperative, important, necessary, preferable, optional, permissible, acceptable, okay, all right, satisfactory, desirable, advisable, sufficient, necessary, mandatory, urgent, vital, crucial, essential, fitting, right, appropriate, better, expedient, and legitimate*.

Comment: What fools these mortals be!  (Shakespeare)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for your answer. How can I migrate this post to English Language Learners? I'm not familiar with these sites... Is there any menu where I can do so? Should I post a new question again on that site?

Comment: @Ssong Posting the same question across Stack Exchange is not allowed. You can delete this question by clicking on **delete** and post it on English Language Learners. It will be faster than the question is migrated by 5 close-votes. You have received only one vote so far. Good luck.

Comment: @Rathony Welcome back, victim of the CPVPV.

Comment: @deadrat Hello. Thanks for your message. Running and Baseball Season just started and I have been quite busy. I am not sure whether I am a victim or aggressor, but what the hell... I need to run and learn. :)

Comment: @Rathony Quite *the revenant*, you are. Welcome back! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Evidence for subjunctive increasingly being avoided (in "natural" contexts)? I suppose that would make British English more natural than American ;-)... It may be used decreasingly everywhere (dunno - would be interested to see some evidence), but would that mean that it is being *avoided*?

Comment: You should have included more context.  It sounds like the quote ended mid-sentence, or at least an implicit referent is missing.

Comment: @Drew: It's [*important that it **be***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=important+that+it+be%2Cimportant+that+it+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimportant%20that%20it%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimportant%20that%20it%20is%3B%2Cc0) recognized that AmE has doggedly stuck to that particular subjunctive usage. But equally, it's *important that it **is*** recognized as perfectly natural in many contexts to avoid the subjunctive in BrE. (Switch the corpus to BrE in that link for the "evidence"! :)

Comment: ...that kind of thing contributes to my general perception that in practice, AmE is more "conservative" than BrE, particularly in matters of syntax, if not so much in vocabulary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, both are used in AmE, and with different meanings (including emphasis on fact vs emphasis on condition). But I see no evidence of Americans "doggedly sticking" to the subjunctive, just because it is less used (increasingly so) in BrE. For one thing, "doggedly" implies a volition, and it suggests but doesn't imply a conscious volition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Nonsense. (1) That's one bit of anecdotal evidence. (2) Neither can be seen as "more conservative", in some general and unspecified evolutionary sense. They have different, *relatively* separate (if not independent) evolutions, with their own histories and interactions (including internal). Thinking that one or the other is "more conservative" - especially without specifying what that means, is not very different from thinking that one or the other is the *real* evolution of English and the other is but a deviation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And still no evidence of "avoidance" in BrE. Disuse does not imply avoidance.

Comment: @Drew: My Google Books link involves tens of thousands of written instances of those two text strings, so relatively speaking it obviously reflects a *significant* difference between BrE and AmE - hardly what I would call "anecdotal evidence". And [here's evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+it+were+me%2Cif+it+was+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20it%20were%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cif%20it%20was%20me%3B%2Cc0) that AmE support for *if it **were** me* is actually increasing, relative to the preferred ***was*** in BrE.

Comment: ...there's no such thing as "real" English. I'm simply making the point that AmE is less tolerant of syntactic changes than BrE, IMHO.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Increasing use in AmE does not imply "*doggedly sticking*" to subjunctive, and it does not mean being "*more conservative*" about existing constructs or being "*less tolerant of syntactic changes*". And decreasing use in BrE does not imply "*avoiding*". These simply mean that the use in one set of speakers is increasing, and in another set it is decreasing. Such claims don't even follow in the single case of the use of subjunctive, let alone as sweeping generalizations about the dialects in general.

Comment: @Drew: You seem excessively antipathetic to my perspective here, so I really don't think there's anything to be gained by me finding further evidence to support my side. Let's just call it a day.

Comment: I haven't watched the speech, but I'd be interested to know if it was scripted or if she was using a teleprompter. I think the **meaning** is: _I think women should be involved in the policies_, but native speakers often find themselves stumbling over some kind of clumsy construct when working through a long speech.

Answer (score -3):

**THE SUBJUNCTIVE = BASE FORM**, is used in noun clauses:

**A) AFTER ADJECTIVES**, (like the ones in the list mentioned before by Rathony) + **THAT**...**(not omitted)** **+ subject + BASE FORM...**),Ex. It is **essential** that **she** **FINISH** that relation.    AND,

**B) AFTER VERBS**, (both lists expressing **ADVICE, NECESSITY OR URGENCY**) ex.(suggest, insist,demand, recommend,propose,request,urge... + **(THAT) - this  may be omitted).**

```
  Ex.   His parents insisted (that) he COME (BASE FORM) to visit them more often.

    The verbs in the list may be in any tense, WHAT FOLLOWS THEM WILL ALWAYS BE A **BASE FORM*= subjunctive.

  The first common example of a different form of subjunctive is found when you learn the PRESENT UNREAL  CONDITIONAL which is not used for past situations BUT FOR ALMOST IMPOSSIBLE CONDITIONS AT PRESENT OR FUTURE.

   ex. If he (WERE) more intelligent, he would not marry that woman.
```

Comment: Please don't use caps as emphasis. We have markup here and you can use bold or italics but caps are horrid and make your text extremely difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry, Catija. but when I press BOLD, words do not get black and CAPS appear instead.

Comment: That's not physically possible. If you use the quick access bold button, it should add a pair of asterisks, not turn on your caps lock key. If that **is** the behavior you are experiencing, you have some major issues with your system. Note that you can use two asterisks before and after text to make it bold or single asterisks to make it italic... no shortcut needed. Either way, you need to remove all of these caps.

Comment: I did not understand why this answer was not accepted. Nothing doing with the previous arguments. This is an answer to the original question.